# Gimp crashes when trying to open EPS file on Windows 7

Tags: gimp, eps

I am going insane on this.

I want to open an EPS file using Gimp 2.8.2 installed on a Windows 7 32-bit system (I think the PC itself is 64-bit but for some reason we have 32-bit Windows installed).

I first tried using [the instructions on the Gimp site](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-external-programs.html). Installed Ghostscript, created the path variable, all nothing doing. Totally useless Gimp message saying "Unable to open the file" (I knew that already).

Hunted all over the Internet and finally came across [this Bugzilla report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=689207#c48). Comment 48 suggested that I should just be able to install 2.8.14 with Postscript support and it should work out of the box.

So I uninstalled Gimp, checked the file had gone from the directory list, and installed the new version. Still can't open the EPS file, and it now crashes Gimp with a message just saying "Plugin crashed: "file-ps.exe".

Just to make sure the images are actually ok I went to my Ubuntu system and installed Gimp (2.8.10 this time), opened the eps file... and it works like a charm, no problem.

If anyone has a solution I would be deeply grateful

Answer (score 0):

check out that post:
http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2013/05/solution-error-open-eps-in-gimp-64-bit-with-ghostscript.html

Solution

> If you have not already, download and install Ghostscript 64-bit
>
> Copy  gsdll64.dll from your Ghostscript bin folder (Eg: C:\Program
> Files\gs\gs9.07\bin) to the GIMP bin folder (Eg: C:\Program
> Files\GIMP 2\bin)
>
> In the GIMP bin folder first a) Rename the file
> libgs-8.dll to libgs-8.old, and then b) Rename gsdll64.dll to
> libgs-8.dll
>
> Restart GIMP and opening EPS images should now work

It worked fine for me with GIMP 2.8.14 and gs9.16 on windows 7 64 bit with a fresh install of GIMP from the Gimp web site.